# Using CSS outside of the browser

Tags: css

Is there a way to use CSS outside of the browser? Let's say I wanted to use it on creating desktop apps for Windows, Mac OSX or any other operating system.

Comment: I think your best bet is to run a browser engine (like Gecko) in app.

Comment: What kind of applications am I able to create with the Gecko engine?

Comment: WebEngines are the same engines browsers use Gecko(Firefox), WebKit (Chrome), etc so they can do about the same as these browsers (regarding html/css/js) and more.

Comment: You can create desktop application using election with Css & HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes CSS is Often Used Outside of a Browser

Yes. When people develop with apps such as **React**, we use CSS and SCSS just like you would on a webpage.

Below is a [sample](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) of using CSS with React using JavaScript

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've heard about that before. Do you know if there are any other ways of implementing CSS into your program?

Comment: Yes. Node.js This was basically invented to allow people to use web languages, such as JavaScript and CSS outside of the browser. Now many apps are built on them. You can check out one I work on called LBRY. On this link, you can see where I have used CSS within the desktop app. https://github.com/lbryio/lbry-desktop/pulls?q=is%3Apr+author%3AInvariant-Change+is%3Aclosed

Comment: See V8: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js#V8

Comment: That is actually really interesting, thanks for your answer! @Invariant Change

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unspecific regarding e.g. the programming language you want to use. There are a lot of frameworks out there used to create desktop frontends. Some of them also use CSS-like notation to define their look, such as [JavaFx](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm).

But if your target is to create a webpage that runs in both browser and as native desktop app, I guess the best way is to run a browser engine inside your app.

Edit to answer your comment: It's not dependent on the programming language but related to the framework you use. Every framework works a bit differently here but some use the CSS notation. But as [StackOverflow is not the place to ask for a list of frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I would recommend you to do some research on your own.

Comment: I was just wondering if I could use CSS with another programming language to style the frontend. Or if every programming language has its own "stylesheets" or whatsoever.